# How to capture a login prompt in Net::SFTP object in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sftp

I'm trying to implement a Ruby script that would send an email notice if login prompt comes up when trying to logon to `Net::SFTP`. The point being that if a logon prompt comes up, there's something wrong with the logon scheme on the SFTP. The question is how do I capture this status in the object itself since the object doesn't actually get initialized unless there's a valid login. Hope this makes sense.

Here's the script I'm attempting:

```
 def logon 
    counter = 0
    begin
      counter += 1
      @@sftp = Net::SFTP.start('<address>', Rails.application.credentials[:username], password: Rails.application.credentials[:password] )
    rescue TimeOutError
      retry if counter <=3
      UserMailer.logon_error.deliver_now if counter == 3
    ensure     
      UserMailer.logon_alert.deliver_now 
    end
  end
```

So if try to create an instance in Rails console like `@@sftp = Net::SFTP.start('moftp.mo.gov', Rails.application.credentials[:missouri_username], password: Rails.application.credentials[:missouri_password] )`

and if there is a problem with password, I get the prompt:

`User@sftp_address password:`

I disguised the address's for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Net::SFTP` uses `Net::SSH` behind the scenes. As it happens `Net::SSH.start` [has an option](http://net-ssh.github.io/net-ssh/Net/SSH.html#method-c-start) `:number_of_password_prompts`, that tells `Net::SSH` how many password prompts to show before it issues an exception. If you set it to zero, `Net::SSH` will fail with `Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed` if the password is missing or invalid.

> :number_of_password_prompts => Number of prompts for the password authentication method defaults to 3 set to 0 to disable prompt for password auth method.

So, you could do:

```
begin
  Net::SSH.start(host, user, password: pass, number_of_password_prompts: 0)
rescue Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed
  # Do something
end
```